# How PhpStorm can recognize incomplete SQL query for check syntax and validation?

Tags: sql, syntax, phpstorm

When I use full PDO query:

```
$db = DB::singleton();
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM promocode WHERE status = 1 AND code='xyz'");
$stmt->execute();
```

PhpStorm recognize table scheme and it suggests syntax & show wrong column name - Nice!

...but, most often I use db like this:

```
public function get($coupon)
{
    /* table:promocode */
    $db = $this->db()->retObj();
    $db->where('status = 1 AND code = ?', [$coupon]);
    return $db->fetch();
}
```

Is there any "magic" comment like *(table:promocode)* to tell PhpStorm that it is DB syntax?

Comment: 1) Recognize that the string is an SQL -- yes -- just add `/** @lang SQL */` just before the actual string (you can also use `GenericSQL` instead of `SQL` if you need just plan syntax highlighting and no checks). 2) To tell that it's a part of some another query (what tables are involved) -- nope; I'm not aware of that and if it will be ever supported for such code.

Comment: strange because I add `/** @lang SQL */` line before `$db->where..` and nothing happen.. (no color change..)

Comment: Please carefully read my comment again. Such comment has to be placed **just before the actual string** and NOT before the whole statement. `$db->where(/** @lang SQL */ 'status = 1 AND code = ?', [$coupon]);`

Comment: right, but would be great id PhpStorm can know what table it is.

Comment: Feel free to file Feature Request on PhpStorm Issue Tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI